# ls sort order inside container

Tags: linux, bash, docker, ls

Running `ls -d` to list directories, print directories in different order if trailing `/` is present in file name. Why is that? What sorting rules apply? and why does this happen only with docker?

With trailing `/`

```
$ docker run --rm ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c "mkdir foo ; mkdir foo-bar ; ls -d foo/ foo-bar/"

foo-bar/
foo/
```

Without trailing `/`

```
$ docker run --rm -it ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c "mkdir foo ; mkdir foo-bar ; ls -d foo foo-bar"

foo
foo-bar
```

Comment: Interesting.What is the output of `type ls` and `ls --version`?

Comment: ls is /bin/ls. version 8.28

Comment: On an Ubuntu container [the GNU coreutils ls documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html#ls-invocation) might say more; but for "how to use Linux tools" questions [su] would be a more appropriate place to ask.  In particular the locale setup will almost certainly be different on the host vs. in a container.

Comment: @David - You are being invited to the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Room (SOCVR)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Information on the room is located at [SOCVR FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). It is a place where folks work together in real time at greater efficiency than the close queues. I think you would be a good fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out I get the same behavior using `sort` command

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c "echo -e 'foo/\nfoo-bar/' | sort"
```

But the sorting order changes when using `sort -d`

```
docker run --rm ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash -c "echo -e 'foo/\nfoo-bar/' | sort -d"
```

Thanks to David for pointing me in the right direction, this is caused by the locale settings as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43465/whats-the-default-order-of-linux-sort)

On bare ubuntu container, POSIX locale is used which has different sorting rules then en_US.
I solved my problem by installing en_US locale in the docker image, and sorting works as expected again.